# Unable to fetch table names using UNION query

Tags: mysql, union, sql-injection

I'm trying to do an sql injection to get a flag on a ctf. I have discovered the place and also the number of columns the query gives. So based on that I'm trying to get the names of the table from information_schema.tables but I'm getting a 500 internal error meaning the query I have written is not right.

I tried this first in order to get the number of columns

```
http://example.come/search.php?search=ball'UNION SELECT 1,1,1,1'
```

and this gave a proper response.

Next I tried

```
http://example.come/search.php?search=ball'UNION SELECT table_name,1,1,1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
```

This query is giving a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Without knowing how `search.php` works it's impossible to answer this.

Comment: The user that runs the SQL query might not have permission to read `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Comment: @Barmar, "For most INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, each MySQL user has the right to access them, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges." Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html